# xpath based on attribute and value

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I need to process same xml, below is partial of it:

```
<response>
<dat id="1">
    <b>
        <i>1</i>
    </b>
    <ds>
        <d>
            <t>2012-12-21</t>
```

what xpath I need to use to select the element "d", which has a parent-parent element "dat" with attribute id="1" and has a child element "t" with value of 2012-12-21?

It is in C#, the application grabs this xml from internet and loads it into XmlDocument. Currently I am doing multiple steps: find note "dat", then find "t" under "dat", then go to parent node "d". I am hoping to have xpath to replace the above multiple steps.

I've tried this xpath: `//dat[@id="1"]/ds/d[t="2012-12-21"]`, but return null node

Thanks.

EDIT:
See below for Dimitre Novatchev's solution.

btw: `//dat[@id="1"]/ds/d[t="2012-12-21"]` worked as well, not sure what happened when I did the test.

Comment: currently I am doing multiple steps: find <dat> with id="1", then select element <t> from this element, and then go the parent <d>.

Comment: Right, it would be helpful if you actually posted the code that does what you've described, and we can provide specific pointers from where you are having a trouble.

Comment: @l46kok, I've tried this xpath: `//dat[@id="1"]/ds/d[t="2012-12-21"]`, but return null node. Thanks.

Comment: I don think with xpath you'll be able to reduce everything to a single step but you might be able to reduce the number of steps.

Comment: @Henry I can see a problem with your xpath, you are trying to select all 'd' nodes with an attribute t="2012-12-21", basically <d t="2012-12-21">. Since in your xml 'd' doesnt have a 't' attribute your are getting null back because no nodes math your xpath.

Comment: @RyanByrne, I am using `d[t="2012-12-21"]`, not `d[@t="2012-12-21"]` which is looking for attribute "t". thanks.

Comment: Is that really what the root element of the XML looks like? If not, does the actual XML have a default namespace?

Comment: @DanielHaley, yes the root is node "response". there is no namespace. I can select node `//dat[@id="1"]`

Comment: Hmm. The XPath looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//dat[@id = 1]/*/d[t[. = '2012-12-21']]
```

This selects all `d` elements that have a `t` child, whose string value is the string `'2012-12-21'`,

and whose grand-parent is a `dat` that has an `id` attribute with numeric value of `1`.

**In case you want to select just one (say the first) of all such elements, use**:

```
(//dat[@id = 1]/*/d[t[. = '2012-12-21']])[1]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//dat[@id = 1]/*/d[t[. = '2012-12-21']]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the (finished) provided XML document:**

```
<response>
    <dat id="1">
        <b>
            <i>1</i>
        </b>
        <ds>
            <d>
                <t>2012-12-21</t>
            </d>
        </ds>
    </dat>
</response>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation (the selected node(s) ) is copied to the output**:

```
<d>
   <t>2012-12-21</t>
</d>
```